# Macbook Pro Dock appearing randomly during movies and applications running

Tags: dock

Macbook Pro with Sierra 10.12.4. When in full screen view, while watching a movie or a video, the dock will randomly appear. Same issue when running application in window mode. Example Skype, not touching the pad and it seems like ghost clicking. The smaller camera window will appear, like I clicked somewhere to do multitasking. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try is a full reset and restart of the Dock. Note you will need to re-add any non-default icons (i.e. apps) that you've added to the Dock - so you may want to take a screenshot of your Dock as a reminder of what you had there. (Or start afresh and only add things as you actually use them).

To reset and restart the Dock, follow these steps:

- Go to Finder
- Press and hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key down
- Now go to the Go menu
- Select the Library option to open the User's *Library* folder. You can let go of the <kbd>option</kbd> key now.
- Go to the Preferences folder (i.e. within the Library folder)
- Find and move the **com.apple.dock.plist** file to the Trash
- Now open Terminal (usually located in Applications > Utilities)
- Enter this command `killall -KILL Dock`
- Press <kbd>enter</kbd>

This should resolve the issue. As mentioned previously, you will need to re-add non-default apps back to the Dock.